# Unable to call my function within my viewmodel injected in my fragment with koin

Tags: dependency-injection, android-koin

I am implementing an android application using koin injection . I have implemented a function within a viewModel injected in my fragment using koin but when i call the function in my fragment , it does not run . How could i solve it ? here is hat i have already implemented :

```
class MyApp :Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidContext(applicationContext)
        modules(appModule)
    }

}
```

}

Here are different modules :

```
val appModule by lazy{//by lazy permet de faire appel au module des que l'on a besoin d'un module
listOf(
    viewModelModule,
    useCaseModule,
    repositoryModule,
    dataModule,
    otherModules
)
```

}

```
val otherModules:Module = module {
    single<USSDApi> { USSDController }
   single<HomePageFragmentPresenterInterface<HomePageFragmentInterface,HomePageFragmentInteractorInterface>> { (view:HomePageFragmentInterface) ->
      HomePageFragmentPresenter (view, get())}
      single { Handler() }
    single<HomePageFragmentInteractorInterface> { HomePageFragmentInteractor(get()) }

}



val viewModelModule: Module = module{
    viewModel { CallViewModel() }
    viewModel { TransactionViewModel(transactionUseCase = get()) }

}

val useCaseModule: Module = module{
    single { TransactionUseCase(transactionRepository = get(),androidApplication()) }

}

val repositoryModule: Module = module{
    single<TransactionRepository>{TransactionRepositoryImpl(remoteApi = get (),androidApplication())}

}

val dataModule: Module = module{
   // single<LocalApi>{ LocalApiImpl(appContext = get()) }
    single { createLagfoClient().create(RemoteApi::class.java) }

}
```

Here is how i initialize my viewModel :

```
   private val viewModel:TransactionViewModel by viewModel()
```

Here is the content of my viewModel :

```
class TransactionViewModel(private val transactionUseCase: TransactionUseCase):ViewModel() {

private val params = MutableLiveData<Params>()

val getTransactionResult: LiveData<Resource<*>> = params.switchMap{ params->

    when (params){

        is Params.GetTransactionInfo -> {
           transactionUseCase.getTransactionInformation(params.numberOfRequest,params.token).asLiveData(contextIO())
        }

        is Params.ValidateTransaction->{
            transactionUseCase.validateTransaction(params.token).asLiveData(contextIO())
        }
    }

}

fun getTransaction(numberOfRequest: Int,token: String){
    params.value=Params.GetTransactionInfo(numberOfRequest,token)
}

fun validateTransaction(token: String){
    params.value=Params.ValidateTransaction(token)
}
sealed class Params {

    data class GetTransactionInfo(val numberOfRequest:Int,val token:String):Params()
    data class ValidateTransaction(val token:String):Params()

}
```

}

When i try to call getTransaction , it does not run :

```
              viewModel.getTransaction(1,Global.token)
```